# Nested modules in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, angularjs-module

I Have 2 differents AngularJs modules : a widgetContainer and a widget.

A widget can be displayed as an independant application or be included into a widgetContainer. A widgetContainer contains 0-N widgets.

If i try to boostrap the widget module into the widgetContainer, angular throw the following error :

> Error: [ng:btstrpd] App already bootstrapped with this element '<div id="childApp">'
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/btstrpd?p0=%26lt%3Bdiv%20id%3D%22childApp%22%26gt%3B

I have reproduce this error in [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PBIyADrP0VpbDBBfen1b?p=preview)

```
<div id="parentApp">
<div ng-controller="MainParentCtrl">
  Hello {{name}} !
  <div id="childApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainChildCtrl">
      Hello {{childName}} !
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT :

Using Dependency injection solve the problem efficiently.

Now, I need to load the widget from a directive.

```
parentApp.directive('widget', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {

      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.setAttribute("ng-controller", "MainChildCtrl");
      div.innerHTML = 'Hello {{childName}} !';
      $element.append(angular.element(div));

    }
  };
}]);
```

The div is created but the childApp module is not loaded inside.
I have updated my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PBIyADrP0VpbDBBfen1b?p=preview)

Comment: seems like you're trying to bootstrap same angular module twice from javascript with same element. Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/btstrpd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('parentApp'), ['parentApp','childApp']);

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4oGw5ROo80OCtURYMVa3?p=preview

Syntax for manual bootstrap is as below irrespective of usage of controllers on elements

```
angular.bootstrap(element, [modules]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to bootstrap both modules. Instead use dependency injection. You only declare one module in your html and you make that module depend upon the other module using angular code. See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#module

Here's your updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/DJvzpCoxLRhyBl77S27k?p=preview

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="childApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainParentCtrl">
      Hello {{name}} !
      <div>
        <div ng-controller="MainChildCtrl">
          Hello {{childName}} !
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

AngularJS:

```
var parentApp = angular.module('parentApp', [])
  .controller('MainParentCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'universe';
  });



var childApp = angular.module('childApp', ['parentApp'])
  .controller('MainChildCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.childName = 'world';
  });


angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('childApp'), ['childApp']);
});
```