# Hide from app.js main module a plug-in inside a component

Tags: angularjs, module, program-entry-point

This one it might be an *oldy* but anyway I guess there are a lot of **front-end developers** with the wisdom.

I'm trying **not** to declare a plug-in into the main module of my application.

Let's say I have the following modularization:

#### SUB-COMPONENT MODULE

```
(function () {
'use strict';

         angular.module('app.modules.table.detail', []);

})();
```

#### COMPONENT MODULE

```
(function () {
'use strict';

         angular.module('app.modules.table', [
                  'app.modules.table.detail'
         ]);

})();
```

#### MAIN APP MODULE

```
(function() {
'use strict';

     angular.module('app.modules', 
        [ 'app.modules.table' <----// inside here is the table.detail 
         ,'app.modules.other.component'
        ]);


     angular.module('app', ['app.modules',

                             'smoothScroll'])
```

So, with this structure, can I hide the **smoothScroll** third-party away from the **app** module array? I just want to declare **app.modules** and that's it for the app.

I tried to include it as a dependency in the component array, but no luck. I've been reading about and I guess it has to be on the app for the $injector to know his $provider.

Anyone have nailed this?

Comment: `$injector` is for services, not modules. Have you considered lazy-loading? [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) might be an option

Comment: I will give it a look if avoids smoothScroll from showing.

Comment: I can see that [ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs) would be another module on the app. 

I was wondering if it is possible to do it without any adds-on. I mentioned `$injector` before because maybe, maybe, I can declare the `smoothScroll` as a service and inject its `$provider`.

Comment: Then your question becomes quite philosophical. You can inject it [differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733304/how-can-i-inject-an-angularjs-module-dependency-without-declaring-it-in-the-depe), or you can hide it within [nested modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044175/nested-modules-in-angularjs)

Comment: I guess yes, it is philosophical. And existencial, where does [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988989/add-dependency-to-angular-module-after-its-been-created) begins and ends.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer myself because it was easier than I thougt.

I was not declaring the *third-party* in the **sub-component / component** modules.

#### CHILD module component

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('app.modules.table.detail', ['smoothScroll']); <-- HERE!
})();
```

#### PARENT module component

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app.modules.table', ['app.modules.table.detail', 'smoothScroll' <--- ALSO HERE
]);
})();
```

So now I can bootstrap the app with no need of declaring the third-party on the main module. Therefore it is hidden from the **main app module** file